# Use $timeout inside custom AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I want to use $timeout inside my custom AngularJS directive, but it's not working. My last implementation looks as following:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('Controller', function($scope){
    $scope.test = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(){ $scope.test = !$scope.test;};
});

App.directive('showTemporary', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
                scope.$watch(attr.showTemporary, function(value){
                element.css('display', value ? '' : 'none');
            });
            $timeout(element.css('display', 'none'), attr.hideDelay);
        }
    }
}]);
```

And markup:

```
<div ng-app='App'>
    <div ng-controller='Controller'>
        <button ng-click='toggle()'>toggle</button>
        <div show-temporary='test' hide-delay="5000"> visible</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass function to $timeout
try:

```
$timeout(function () {
 element.css('display', 'none')
}, attr.hideDelay);
```

Also you should observe attributes, not watch.

```
attr.$observe('showTemporary', function(value){
                element.css('display', value ? '' : 'none');
            });
```

Your html was also broken:

```
<div show-temporary="{{test}}" hide-delay="5000"> visible</div>
```

Comment: thanks, you helped me very much, now element disapears aster delay, but only once, next task for me is to make delay work with on every click, I'll be very grateful, if you help me, here is the working fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5j08dn5s/)

Comment: @snowfinch27 here you go, just remove condition in your $observe http://jsfiddle.net/dtjfojt1/1/ and remember to use $observe, not $watch

Comment: thank you very much, I'm pretty new to AngularJS, sorry for dumb mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the  [$timeout docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout). The first parameter is FUNCTION, so you probably want it to be like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
    element.css('display', 'none')
}, attr.hideDelay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish here but this is how you should use $timeout

```
$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);

$timeout(function() {element.css('display', 'none')}, attr.hideDelay);
```